# Missing functionality between Accept-Language header and ResourceBundle

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

Google foo failed me. I want to find out if there is a standard "by the book" way of transforming the input locales from Accept-Language header to correct ResourceBundle.

`ResourceBundle::getBundle()` method(s) accepts a **single** locale but Accept-Language can have multiple locales weighted by index, eg: `de;q=1.0, sl;q=0.9`.

Current code:

```
@Context
private HttpServletRequest request;

public String getString(String key) {
        ResourceBundle i18n = ResourceBundle.getBundle("locale/strings", this.request.getLocale());
        return i18n.getString(key);
}
```

The problem is that `getLocale()` returns the preferred locale, in this case `de`. If **available** resource bundles are `sl` and `en`, this will try to find `de` and then fallback to `en`, but the actual expected result by the client is `sl`!

My question is basically, do I have to implement a custom fallback code that iterates over `HttpServletRequest.getLocales()` (I don't want to reinvent the wheel..) or is there a more standard and straightforward way of doing this? I'd also settle for some 3rd party lib that fills this gap.

Custom solution so far:

```
@RequestScoped
public class Localization {

    @Context
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    private ResourceBundle i18n;

    @PostConstruct
    void postConstruct() {
        //List of locales from Accept-Language header
        List<Locale> locales = Collections.list(request.getLocales());

        if (locales.isEmpty()) {
            //Fall back to default locale
            locales.add(request.getLocale());
        }

        for (Locale locale : locales) {
            try {
                i18n = ResourceBundle.getBundle("bundles/translations", locale);
                if (!languageEquals(i18n.getLocale(), locale)) {
                    //Default fallback detected
                    //The resource bundle that was returned has different language than the one requested, continue
                    //Only language tag is checked, no support for detecting different regions in this sample
                    continue;
                }
                break;
            }
            catch (MissingResourceException ignore) {
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean languageEquals(Locale first, Locale second) {
        return getISO2Language(first).equalsIgnoreCase(getISO2Language(second));
    }

    private String languageGetISO2(Locale locale) {
        String[] localeStrings = (locale.getLanguage().split("[-_]+"));
        return localeStrings[0];
    }

    public ResourceBundle i18n() {
        return this.i18n;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write an Interceptor, there you can set the language you want and apply the logic you want into a ThreadLocal or pass it down.

i.e you check against the available languages and define an order or set a default.

If you use Spring, you could then set LocaleContextHolder manualy or use the LocaleContextResolver instead of writing a own interceptor.

Comment: I know how I can handle this with custom code, the question is more along the lines of whether there is some standard function or lib that would get this done since it's such an obvious problem.

Comment: in Spring use ResourceBundleMessageSource instead